# check to see if service is fully stopped before trying to start service

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make sure the batch file knows the service "Tomcat7" is fully stopped before trying to start the "Tomcat7" service again. I know "NET STOP" and "NET START" are supposed to wait to return until each have fully stopped or started, but I have seen cases where it continues on anyways, possibly due to a long timeout wait sometimes.

```
@ECHO OFF

net stop Tomcat7

rd /s /q "C:\storefront\live\work"
rd /s /q "C:\storefront\live\logs"

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query Tomcat7 ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" EQ "STOPPED" (
    net start Tomcat7
  )
)
```

Comment: There is a typo in `if /I "%%H" EQ "STOPPED" (`. Should be `EQU` instead of `EQ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sc query Tomcat7` to get the status of the service.

Comment: thanks for the input Steven. Do you think the for statement above looks good with your use of sc query?

Comment: You may consider adding a short wait between the for loop iterations.  Use the `timeout` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
sc start stisvc || Echo Service Not Fully Exited
```

Doesn't this do what you want? Remember we try things and catch errors, not test and then do. Think about why.